# Migrate mongodb collections and indexes excluding data

Tags: mongodb

I have two environments DEV and STAGE and I need to take **all** of my `collections` from a DEV database to a database in STAGE.

Currently using **mongodump** to get all of my collections and indexes, which appears to work very well.

`>mongodump --host 192.168.#.# --port 27019 --db MyDB`

Then I am using **mongorestore** to populate STAGE with the appropriate collections and indexes.

`>mongorestore --host 192.168.#.# --port 27019 --db test "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\dump\MyDB"`

My collections and indexes come across perfectly, however, my collection content comes as well. I have not found a way to exclude my actual data inside my collections...is this doable?  Can I remove files from the output of **mongodump** to only have my `collections` and their 'indexes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB is schemaless so basically there is no point of restoring empty collections. Collections are created on the fly when you do a write.

I understand you just want to restore collection's metadata as indexes etc., I don't know what driver are you using but I would suggest you deal with this problem on the application level by writing a routine that creates the indexes etc.

Also removing the bson files and keeping only the metadata files from mongodump as you suggest will work (or at least it works in my case with mongo V 3.0.5 with wiredtiger engine) **but is not documented** as far as I know.

An other alternative could be to use -query option on mongodump to specify documents to include i.e: {_id:a_non_existing_id} but this option is applicable only to collection level dumps.

Comment: I thought about trying an invalid query but felt like I was going outside of the norms.  I think keeping it at the application level should work well, keeps it in source and easily maintained.  Appreciate the helpful feedback and recommendations!

Comment: v 2.6 doesnt seem to like not having the .bson files =(...mongorestore connects but doesnt seem to actually perform any operations.

Comment: @afreeland :-)  Out of curiosity I tried it and worked probably it has to do with wiredtiger or OS (I tried that on a linux box). Anyway as you say, application is the best solution for consistency and other reasons.

Comment: What is common practice with application level.  During app initialization? When accessing the collection? Storing collection and indexes in a config file? Is there any documented recommended practices from mongo?

Comment: I haven't seen any documented best practice for this. What I usually do these things along with some sanity checks immediately after I first establish a connection to mongoDB.
create_index is a cheap operation on an empty collection or when index is already there.